# get an id from one page and store it in another page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a javascript function below:

```
var alphabet = [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" ];  

function generateRandomString(strLength) {     
    var output = "";     
    for (var i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {         
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);         
        output += alphabet[randomIndex];     }     
        return output; }  

        function getSession() {     
            var randomDiv = document.getElementById("randomStrings");     
            newText = generateRandomString(3);     
            randomDiv.innerHTML = newText; 
            }
```

What this function does is retrieve any of the letters 3 times and display it e.g. AGH, TRY, MNK etc.

This is displayed in a paragraph like below:

```
<p id="randomStrings"></p>
```

This is all done in the create_session.php file.

Now what I want is that I want `id="randomStrings"` from the create_session.php file and store it in another page (QandATable.php). How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript to copy the value you want to a hidden input field in a form and the submit the form to the QandATable.php. Then, you can you $_POST array to access the value you just sent.

Comment: because there is a possibility of having many values e.g LKH, AAP, RTE etc what do I put in "value". At moment I have written this <input type="hidden" name="random" value="..." />, but I don't know what to put in value as it can output one value from a possibility of 100s of values

Comment: You can make an input field for EACH value you create and access them as an array in the second page: <input type="hidden" name="random[]" value="" />... notice the name: **random[]**, just put it like that in each input field... or you can use comma to separate them and have only one input field... possibilities are endless and it all depends on what you need

Comment: Comma solution is certainly better. Less output code + it's easy to explode it into array of values using PHP function explode(). +1